# Запятая в сложносочиненных предложениях 4

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли здесь запятая? Обстоятельство *при отрицательных температурах* здесь общее, или *при движении* - это уже другое обстоятельство и, соответственно, нужна запятая?

При отрицательных температурах многие резины твердеют (,) и при движении начинается утечка.

Answer (score 2):

По-моему,здесь нет акцента на общем обстоятельстве, хотя всё происходит при отрицательной температуре. Температура важна для объяснения твёрдости резины, а уж твёрдость влияет на утечку. Думаю, запятая нужна.

ТемпературЫ здесь, вероятно, профессионализм? Текст научный? Иначе будет грамматическая ошибка, ведь у слова температура нет мн. числа, только ед.

Comment: Так же, как и у давления?

Comment: Да. Должно быть "при отрицательных показателях температуры", но синоптики говорят при "температурах" - это профессионализм, может, и автомобилисты - не знаю

Answer (score 1):

Постановка второй запятой связана скорее  с наличием обстоятельства "при движении", которое относится ко второму предложению:

Сравнить: При отрицательных температурах многие резины твердеют  и начинается утечка (газа).